# RSpec create method for build message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm still learning how to test controllers with rspec. I've got a simple message app where one user can create message to another user (only logged users can write messages). I didn't used devise to log in or sign up users, this app is as simple as possible just for rspec learning.

I've got `create` method in `Messages` controllers which I want to test:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def create
    message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    if message.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Here is my spec

```
RSpec.describe MessagesController, type: :controller do
  describe 'signed user' do
    before do
      user = User.create!(username: 'John', password: 'test123')
    end

    describe 'GET #create' do
      it 'create message' do
        expect do
          post :create, params: { message: { body: 'Please work!' } }
        end.to change(Message, :count).by(1)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With an error

> expected `Message.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

I think I have to log in user but how to do so without using factory bot?

EDIT
As suggested in comment, this should be useful

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def require_user
    if !logged_in?
      flash[:error] = 'You must be logged in to perform that action'
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you paste what's in `require_user` method?It's custom right? as you said devise is not used

Comment: yes, it's custom method, post updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `@current_user` for your spec to pass ie:

```
 before do
    user = User.create!(username: 'John', password: 'test123')
    assign(:current_user, user)
 end
```

See [assign](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FViewAssigns:assign) docs for reference

If assign `@current_user` doesn't work, try stub `current_user` instead ie

```
     before do
        user = User.create!(username: 'John', password: 'test123')
        allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
     end
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't worked - ```undefined method `assign'```

Comment: I may know why, are you on Rails 5?

Comment: Yup Rails 5.2.1.1